# How to read and write files in a reactive way using InputStreamand OutputStream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to read an Excel file in manipulate it or add new data to it and write it back out. I am also trying to do this a complete reactive process using Flux and Mono. The Idea is to return the resulting file or bytearray via a webservice.

My question is how do I get a InputStream and OutputStream in a non blocking way?

I am using the Apache Poi library to read and generate the Excel File.

I currently have a solution based around a mix of Mono.fromCallable() and Blocking code getting the Input Stream.

For example the webservice part is as follows.

```
@GetMapping(value = API_BASE_PATH + "/download", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Mono<ByteArrayResource> download() {
    Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> createExcel = excelExport.createDocument(false);

    return createExcel.then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        excelExport.getWb().write(outputStream);
        return new ByteArrayResource(outputStream.toByteArray());
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()));
}
```

And the Processing of the file:

```
public Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> createDocument(boolean all) {
    Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> entries = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("Timesheet Template.xlsx").getInputStream();
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        log.info("Created document");

        if (all) {
            //all entries
        } else {
            entries = service.findByMonth(currentMonthName).log("Excel Export - retrievedMonths").sort(Comparator.comparing(TimeKeepingEntry::getDateOfMonth)).doOnNext(timeKeepingEntry-> {
                this.populateEntry(sheet, timeKeepingEntry);
            });
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error Importing File", e);
    }
    return entries;
}
```

This works well enough but not very in line with Flux and Mono. Some guidance here would be good. I would prefer to have the whole sequence non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `WorkbookFactory.create()` operation is blocking, so you have to perform that operation using imperative code. However fetching each timeKeepingEntry can be done reactively. Your code would looks something like this:

```
public Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> createDocument() {
    return Flux.generate(
        this::getWorkbookSheet,
        (sheet, sink) -> {
            sink.next(getNextTimeKeepingEntryFrom(sheet));
        },
        this::closeWorkbook);
}
```

This will keep the workbook in memory, but will fetch each entry on demand when the elements of the Flux are requested.

Comment: Hi Not sure how this actually helps, or works. The idea is to read the file in as a template, retrieve the data from the database and populate the sheet as the line did above. My question was more how I can make this non-blocking. But as you quite rightly said unfortunately it is blocking due to the nature of WorkBookFactory. A slightly more clear explanation would be helpful.